# How to merge 2 dataframes based off of 2 different parameters pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two different dataframes

df1 looks like this

```
 Item Number      UOM    Contract Cost    Quantity
  600543          CS        54.65           10
  300216          EA        45.79           15
  401799          CS        118.03          67
```

df2

```
 Item Number     UOM    New Contract Cost     
   600543        EA           52.78
   300216        CS           42.90
   401799        CS           140.00
```

I need to merge the two dataframes so that if 'Item Number' **and** 'UOM' match, the two rows are combined. For the example dataframes above, my expected output would be:

df3

```
Item Number         UOM        Contract Cost    Quantity     New Contract Cost 
  401779            CS              118.03        67                140.00
```

If both parameters are not met, I don't want it included in the new dataframe. Very new to this. I have successfully done an inner merge based on a single column name, but can't figure out how to combine that second parameter. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

that must be :

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=["UOM","Item Number"])

Look at how "on" is defined here :

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

And by default, merge will do a inner join, so you will only have matching records

Comment: Hi, if this is the correct answer, can you accept it ?